# 2 DAX questions (adding rows from one table depending on condition based on same table and another table)

Tags: dax

imagine that you have 3 tables:

```
Table Fact Seller  : seller_code,  seller_name,  manager_code
Table Fact Manager : manager_code, manager_name 
Table Fact Product : product_code, product_name, seller_code
```

Relations have been made between keys.

I want to calculate two aspects:

1) The number of active sellers. A Seller is active if it has any (1 or more) product in Fact Product.

i would like to know how i can i calculate this. it would be something like
 `=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact Seller'[seller_code]);[filter here]))`

In `[filter here]` i need something like `FILTER(COUNTROWS('Fact Product';'Fact Product'[manager_code])>=1)`, to get only the sellers from fact seller who have at least one product in fact product. I think i need to use the keyword `VALUES()` but i didn't find the correct syntax.

i would like to know what is better way or pattern for doing this.

2) The number of sellers with managers. Please note that when data is retrieved, if a seller has no manager the field manager_code has value "-1". So i can do this:

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact Seller'[seller_code]);FILTER('Fact Seller';'Fact Seller'[manager_code]>=1))
```

So this is a filter inside the table. This works, but i would like to know if there is a better way or pattern for this.

Can you help out ?

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

For your first question you can create a [calculated column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413492(v=sql.110).aspx) called "Active". This will determine if the seller for that row is active or not.

```
=IF(
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Fact Product'),
    ALL('Fact Product'),
    'Fact Product'[seller_code]=EARLIER('Fact Seller'[seller_code])
  )<1,FALSE(),TRUE()
 )
```

Now you can create a measure which uses this new column to get the total Active Sellers

```
ActiveSellers:=CALCULATE(
 DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact Seller'[seller_code]),
 'Fact Seller'[Active]=TRUE()
)
```

For your second question, your statement can be shortened to

```
SellersWithManagers:=CALCULATE(
 DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact Seller'[seller_code]),
 'Fact Seller'[manager_code]<>-1
)
```